# Save exec output to <properties></properties> section of pom.xml for use in later maven phase

Tags: java, maven, docker, properties

I have a maven java project that `docker build`s a docker image and then `docker save`s the image as an artifact of the build using the `io.fabric8.docker-maven-plugin` plugin.

When I build the docker image, I would like to get the size and add it to metadata so we can see how big the image is before it is uncompressed.

The `io.fabric8.docker-maven-plugin` plugin does not have a way of getting the exact size of generated docker image, so I am currently using the `org.codehaus.mojo.exec-maven-plugin` plugin to grab the size of the image like so:

```
<plugin>
    <!-- generate metadata about docker image -->
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-docker-metadata</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>docker</executable>
                <commandlineArgs>image inspect ${project.docker.image}:${project.version} --format='{{.Size}}' >> ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/Docker-Image-Size</commandlineArgs>
                <workingDirectory>.</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Currently I can put the output into the `Docker-Image-Size` file, but I need a way to make it available as a property that can be referenced in the meta-data section that generates the meta-data file.

**How can I save this exec output to the `<properties>/<properties>` section of the `pom.xml` file to be used later in a different phase?**

Do I need to use a properties file, or can I just save it as `${docker.image.size}`?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in one run of Maven. Instead, you could first run goals or scripts to manipulate the pom and afterwards start the Maven build.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the size until I build the image with `mvn`. Given that when I run `mvn install` it builds the image, only then do I have the image present on the host to use as input for the `docker inspect` command.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot change the POM during the build itself. So I guess the answer is that your requested behaviour is impossible.

Comment: Write the results of your docker image query either to a temporary file in target, or directly into your meta-data file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I cannot directly edit any properties that already exist in the `<properties>/<properties>` section of the `pom.xml`.**

*However*, the answer I came up with is to use the `org.codehaus.gmaven.gmaven-plugin` plugin to run shell script, edit the output, and save it to a variable that can be used later in the `pom.xml` file. Note that his variable is not actually defined anywhere in the file except for in the `org.codehaus.gmaven.gmaven-plugin` plugin section.

(*Putting an empty variable in the `<properties>/<properties>` section of the `pom.xml`always makes the variable empty.*)

I used the `org.codehaus.gmaven.gmaven-plugin` plugin like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <script>docker image inspect ${project.docker.image}:${project.version} --format='{{.Size}}</script>
                </properties>
                <source>
                    def command = project.properties.script
                    def process = command.execute()
                    process.waitFor()

                    def text = process.in.text.trim()
                    // Remove single quotes that surround number output
                    def number = text.substring(1, text.length()-1);
                    project.properties.dockerImageSize = number
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The metadata section then uses the variable like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>manifest</goal>
                </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Bundle-Category>Thing</Bundle-Category>
            <Bundle-Activator>com.company.thing.impl.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
            <Bundle-Vendor>${company.vendor}</Bundle-Vendor>
            <Bundle-ContactAddress>${company.contactAddress}</Bundle-ContactAddress>
            <Bundle-Copyright>${company.copyright}</Bundle-Copyright>
            <Bundle-LicenseType>${company.licenseType}</Bundle-LicenseType>
            <Bundle-Description>${company.description}</Bundle-Description>
            <Bundle-DockerImageSize>${dockerImageSize}</Bundle-DockerImageSize>
            <Import-Package>
                com.company.thing.api*;version="[0.0.10,1.0.0)",
                *
            </Import-Package>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```